# How do you use the word "aged"?

Tags: word-usage

which one is correct please: "children aged eleven to fifteen" or "children aged eleven to fifteen years" or "children aged eleven to fifteen years old"?
Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446558/the-grammaticality-and-function-of-people-ages-20-to-30-as-opposed-to-people

Answer (score 1):

All three exemples are correct, probably the first one is the more common usage:

***[Aged](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/aged)***  [not before noun] of the age of:

> - They have two children aged six and nine.
> - Volunteers aged between 25 and 40

(OLD)

From [Norwich Murderrs](https://books.google.it/books?id=DUtuTBJymmIC&pg=PA108&dq=%22aged%20six%20and%20nine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwido-nC5-LdAhUFjosKHdMMDDQQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%22aged%20six%20and%20nine%22&f=false):

> She did ask for custody of her two youngest children, ***aged six and nine years*** (some reports vary these ages slightly), seemingly not mentioning a twelve-year-old son.

From [Monitoring Systems for Agricultural and Rural Development Projects](https://books.google.it/books?id=BQJTrkt_DugC&pg=PA214&dq=%22six%20to%20nine%20years%20old%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF24ra6OLdAhURlosKHZXnByMQ6AEIKjAB#v=onepage&q=%22six%20to%20nine%20years%20old%22&f=false):

> A national census of heights of all school children, ***aged six to nine years old,*** entering the first grade of primary school, was carried out.

Comment: I would view "aged six years old" as redundancy. Either "aged six years" or "six years old",

Answer (score 0):

Children aged eleven to fifteen (11 to 15).

Children aged eleven to fifteen years (11 to 15 years).

Children aged eleven to fifteen years old (11 to 15 years old).

The first and the second sentences are grammatical.  As for the third one, we don't use old with aged; so "old" is redundant in the sentence.

Further, it's more common to write "aged 11 to 15 (in figures)" than "aged eleven to fifteen (in words").  Also, the first sentence is more common than the second one.